# My ExpressVPN Firefox extension randomly disconnects (or won’t connect at all) in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: firefox, internet, vpn, disconnect

Also, some websites (lichess.org) mysteriously won’t load without express vpn being connected; they were working just fine and then just stopped loading; I made no changes to anything that I’m aware of.

I played around with DNS and IpV4/IpV6 but I can’t find any guide/tutorial that looks the same as my ‘edit network settings’ window.

When I boot up sometimes expressvpn will connect right away and stay running for some time then it’ll disconnect; sometimes it’ll reconnect and other times it just won’t!

I’m desperate for a stable internet connection.

Any help is much appreciated!

Proxy = automatic

Ipv4 Settings: Method = Automatic (DHCP) Addresses Only.
DNS Servers = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
I ticked: Require Ipv4 addressing for this connection to complete.

Ipv6 Settings: Method = Automatic

My UFW firewall is disabled. (I’d like to enable it.)

I uninstalled ClamTK (though I do want to run an anti-virus); and I’m unsure if ClamAV is still active.

Changing protocol will sometimes (randomly) get it to connect.

Is it normal for express vpn to disconnect like this? Are there better VPNs for Ubuntu? It just disconnected now but reconnected on it’s own...

Comment: I use nordvpn , and occassionally have your problem, but there are many other problems with network manager (and USB ethernet adapter) . to tie it down i am working on setting up ufw to only accept the vpn traffic...  https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/how-to-make-a-vpn-kill-switch-in-linux-with-ufw/   .... the terminal command dig <vpnaddress> will get your vpn ip# to allow. vpn using  tcp apparently is more stable (using a ##tcp.ovpn file).

Comment: DNS I set sudo rm -r /etc/resolv.conf ... (if permission denied, chattr -i) ... sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf .... nameserver #### ....  nameserver #####.... sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf.... sudo reboot now. though keep an eye on that file.

Comment: Thanks pierrely! Hoping for more comments; Ideally an example of what my exact settings should be. I'm a newbie so the above is slightly intimidating.

I haven't changed my settings and sometimes my vpn stays connected for hours and still sometimes it won't connect at all.

Comment: @UITF... "it is the ubuntu way".... you'd have to lookup some of those terms and that will get you more comprehensive articles or answers (mostly on this site). yes it might be fruitless and when you have it right "the Ubuntu way" will change it on you, but that is how it is. for example, my autoconnet setting with nordvpn app . sometimes does and sometimes does not autoconnect the vpn on reboot. I have even considered ditching network manager, or diving into the source code to see what it does, or use inotifywait app to monitor what is accessing or changing the relevant files.

Comment: the only easy answer is unintall reinstall nm (or the whole ubuntu) or wait for updates and hope for the best. (I recommend full system eg clonezilla backups first)

Comment: Any thoughts as to what may have stopped certain websites from loading while others load up fine regardless of which browser I'm using? The only reason I'm so concerned with my VPN is it has to be on now to access certain sites (lichess.org). Possible fixes? Thanks :)

Comment: just a half baked guess, have you tried disabling ipv6? another one is to go through a web proxy site. or torproject.org/ tor browser bundle and see if it goes through that way. search for any express von alternative dns numbers. (and to make a point, as I went looking just now, for the first time, I cannot even get to https://yippy.com (two browsers) to do that for you... maybe chinese/russian/munchkin hackers, maybe just they are down, for the first time for me.).

Comment: I tried disabling ipv6 when I was desperately trying to get VPN to function; it's now set to automatic and working most of the time so I'm scared to play with any settings; though I will look into everything you wrote. 

Yes croxyproxy allowed me to access lichess.org without a VPN. 

But I can't browse craigslist through croxyproxy or my VPN and it won't load at all otherwise.

Are there any other Linux Distributions which offer 100% reliable VPN/internet connections?

Comment: just joking, but maybe not http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/index.html